# Error while mounting volume "mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown"

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

Part of my yaml is as shown below. When I apply this stateful set, I get an error. Where am I going wrong?

My config map has data for appsettings.requestforwarder.json

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/f2c0dd70-d0b0-4c69-81b7-412270661a7e/volume-subpaths/xyz-volume/xyz/0" to rootfs at "/app/appsettings.json" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown
```

```
image: sdfldkajlkj:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
            - name: xyz-volume
              mountPath: /app/appsettings.json
              subPath: appsettings.json
      volumes:
        - name: xyz-volume
          configMap:
            name: xyz-configuration
            optional: false
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake from my side. The config map had data "appsettings.xyz.json". The mouth path must be as shown below to load it successfully.

```
mountPath: /app/appsettings.xyz.json
```